# iterate over a sparse array, skip over undefined, but keep the original index

Tags: javascript

I have a sparse array like this

```
> arr = ["a",,"b"]
[ 'a', <1 empty item>, 'b' ]
```

I want to iterate over the values, skipping the `undefined`s, but keep the original index.

From the example array above I want `[0,"a"]` then `[2,"b"]`.

When I just naively loop over the array I will get the `undefined`s

```
> for(let [i,v] of arr.entries()) {console.log(i,v)}
0 a
1 undefined
2 b
```

I learned that `forEach` skips the `undefined`s

```
> arr.forEach((v,i)=>console.log(i,v))
0 a
2 b
```

But this will not work if I want to `yield` from the loop. It seems to be not possible to yield from inside the function.

I could filter the `undefined`s but then I lose the index.

```
> for(let [i,v] of arr.filter(v=>v!==undefined).entries()) {console.log(i,v)}
0 a
1 b
```

It seems I have to do it manually

```
> for(let [i,v] of arr.entries()) { if(v!==undefined) {console.log(i,v)} }
0 a
2 b
```

Or this abomination

```
> for(let [i,v] of [...arr.entries()].filter(([i,v])=>v!==undefined)) {console.log(i,v)}
0 a
2 b
```

Is there a better/more concise way?

The arrays are not huge. Performance is not really an issue.

---

Background

The sparse array is created like this

```
let arr = [];
for(let [i,v] of somecalculations(somedata)) {
    arr[i] = v;
}
```

There is no constraint of how the indexes come out (other than that it stays in sane dimensions). I can get something like this `["a","b","c"]` or like this `[,,,,,"a"]` or like this `[]`.

And to make things more interesting I do not just iterate over the array but iterate pairwise (the `[1,2],[2,3]` variant)

```
function *pairwise(arr) {
    let it = [...arr.entries()].filter(([i,v])=>v!==undefined).values();
    let curr = it.next();
    let next = it.next();
    while(!next.done) {
        yield [curr.value, next.value];
        curr = next;
        next = it.next();
    }
}
```

For an array like this `["a",,"b","c"]` the output is `[[0,"a"],[2,"b"]]` and `[[2,"b"],[3,"c"]]`. If there is just one element in the array then there is no output.

And consume like this

```
for(let [[i1,v1],[i2,v2]] of pairwise(arr)) {
    // do calculation on pair
    // aggregate results
}
// further calculations on results
```

Comment: they aren't `undefined` they are empty

Comment: you can use `for...in` which only visits enumerable properties (empty slots aren't enumerable, thus my comment above) but keep in mind it returns indexes as strings, and *will* visit non-integer enumerable properties

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick example using [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#array_iteration_and_for...in) which only visits enumerable properties (empty slots aren't enumerable). The advantage is that the generator doesn't have to prep the array ahead of time. But keep in mind it returns indexes as strings (here rectified with a [unary +](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus)), and *will* visit non-integer enumerable properties.

```js
function* pairwise(arr) {
  let prev;
  for (const i in arr) {
    let curr = [+i, arr[i]];

    if (prev) yield [prev, curr];

    prev = curr;
  }
}

const a = ['a', , 'b', 'c'];

for (const p of pairwise(a)) {
  console.log(p);
}
```